# Why is the line number appended to a cucumber command line user variable?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Here is my cucumber command

```
cucumber features/xxx.feature -l 409 ENVIRONMENT=LOCAL BROWSER=true
```

When I do `puts ENV['ENVIRONMENT']`, the value is `LOCAL:409`. It is the same with `ENV['BROWSER']`.

Because of this, my scripts are failing as this append is not expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the parsing of the CLI arguments. This appears to have been like this since the [original implementation of the lines option](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/commit/49cee3723b4b9ea3e5112087a7573714ed40b27b). You can see the following in the [`Cucumber::Cli::Options` on Line 142-144](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/b02e28388bb72eb4d193c1f257e6f3d71d965bce/lib/cucumber/cli/options.rb#L142-L144):

```
@args.map! { |a| "#{a}:#{@options[:lines]}" } if @options[:lines]

extract_environment_variables
```

This `map!` statement adds the line number to each of the remaining arguments, which includes:

1. The specified feature file, `features/xxx.feature` (good)
2. Each environment variable (bad)

The `extract_environment_variables` needs to come before the `map!` so that the environment variables are not included in `@args` when it is mapped.

Aside from waiting for the bug to be fixed in Cucumber, which I have opened in [Issue 1064](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/issues/1064), your only option appears to use the `FILE:LINE` syntax rather than the `-l` option:

```
cucumber features/xxx.feature:409 ENVIRONMENT=LOCAL BROWSER=true
```